# Rails: CSV Import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import

i genereated an csv with columns id, task, description, created_at, updated_at

```
 create_table "tasks", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "task"
t.string   "description"
t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
```

I opened the sqlite Konsole

```
   rails db
   .separator ','
   .C:/User/jkl/Desktop/tasks.csv
```

I get error datatype mismatch.
I dont fill in created_at and updated_at, but this is from rails to null => false.

How do you import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do it via a ruby script:

```
require 'csv'

def import
  CSV.foreach('path/to/file.csv', :col_sep => ';', :headers => true) do |row|
    Task.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
end
```

This works assuming your CSV headers match your column names, like so:

```
task;description
"Task 1";"Paint the fence"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes looks good. As my Path i filled in an absolute path to my csv-file. It has the same grammatic as yours, but it doesnt import. I executed the file with ruby import.rb

Comment: Oh now I see you're using windows. Your path probably will look like `C:\\User\\jkl\\Desktop\\tasks.csv`